# Prove that if $2\cdot\dim V\leq \dim U + \dim W $ then $V=U+W$

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $V$ be a finite vector space and $U,W$ be subspaces. Prove that if $2\cdot\dim V\leq \dim U + \dim W $ then $V=U+W$.

My progress:

Since $U,W$ are subspaces of $V$ then $\dim W\leq\dim V$ and $\dim U\leq\dim V$ therefore $\dim W+\dim U\leq\dim V+\dim V=2\dim V$.

From what is given in the question $2\cdot\dim V=\dim U+\dim W$.

How do I continue from here? From the dimension theorem I can say that $2\dim V=\dim(U\cap W)+\dim(U+W)$, but how do I formally continue this? (Question was if it's correct in the first place, but logically I think it is).

Comment: Is the question posed correctly? Because since $U,W$ are subspaces of $V$ their dimension is smaller or equal than $V$ and hence the inequality is actually reversed as you showed. The only possibility for the inequality to be true is $U=V$ and $W=V$

Comment: I feel like the conclusion should be that $U$ and $W$ are actually the whole space.

Comment: We always have $\dim V\ge\text{dim }U$ for $U$ a subspace. So the given inequality implies that both $U$ and $W$ equal $V$, and the result is trivial.

Comment: I was really close then, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a little calculation the question is trivial:

Let $\;V\;$ be a linear space, $\;U,W\le V\;$ .For any $\;n\in\Bbb N\;$, the maximal dimension a proper subspace of $\;V\;$ can have is $\;n-1\;$ , and if at least one of $\;U,V\;$ is a maximal proper subspaces of $\;V\;$ , then

$$2\dim V=2n\le \dim U+\dim W=n+n-1=2n-1\iff 0\le -1$$

which is absurd. Thus the only possibility for $\;2\dim V\le\dim U+\dim V\;$ to be true is if that both $\;U=W=V\;$ and thus $\;V=U=W=U+W\;$ trivially.